# Vscode work on server with git (php develoment)

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, sftp

In vscode, is it possible to work on a remote dir (centos) which is maintained by git and let the git on the server do the git commits etc?

I want to have a situation that I can save a php file on the server and let nginx serve the file immediately wothout having to do any merges or something. I don't have a server enviroment on my pc similar to the web environment so a local repo isn't really gonna help me in previewing my work as I develop.

Basically I want: save file on remote server, f5 in my browser will show the result and have it all pushed to a repo without using the command line on the server. Is this doable?

I already have the webserver and git repo setup.

I'm aware of the git and ssh support in vscode but not sure if this will do what I want since it will probably just use a local copy when using git.

I'm also open to other suggestions/ editors, I won't be the only one with this wish :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1.) Use [SFTP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp) in VSCode, which has a [GitHub repository here](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp).You can configure your settings according to various examples provided there. It allows you to connect,upload/download files to/from the server respectively.

2.) You can use Git in a local repository on your computer. Whenever you do any changes in the files, they get tracked by Git and you can then commit/push them into your GitHub repository right there using either VSCode buttons or terminal in VSCode. Also,those changes will get uploaded to your server simultaneously depending on your config.

Here is some example code for upload setting you can use in your `sftp.json` file once you start using this extension.

```
{
  "uploadOnSave": false,
  "watcher": {
        "files": "**",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "autoDelete": true
    },
    "ignore": [
        "**/.vscode/**",
        "**/.git/**",
    ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up using VS Code Remote Development

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview